# how to make discord bot complete command only once?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a command, that bot will be able to complete only once.
here is my code so far:

```
@client.command()
counter=0
async def once(ctx):
    if counter == 0:
        command
    counter+=1
```

it doesn't work, and instead says

> invalid syntax

Comment: Can you provide more code and full error log, debugging with what you have provided is not possible.

Comment: @BijayRegmi it just says "invalid syntax" and highlights in red "c" in first "counter". Nothing else

Comment: exchange @client statement and counter statement

Comment: decorator should be above the respective function

Comment: @BijayRegmi Ignoring exception in command wew:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aven-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aven-\Desktop\bee\bots\dating murder game\dadting murder game.py", line 20, in wew
    if counter>1:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
(1)

Comment: @BijayRegmi Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aven-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\aven-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aven-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
(2)

Comment: @BijayRegmi     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment       (3)

Comment: @BijayRegmi what i wrote above was error log

Comment: @BijayRegmi nvm, I forgot to add "client." before "counter"